# How do I plot multiple functions in matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have the following code:

```
def f(x):
    return x

def g(x):
    return x*x

from math import sqrt
def h(x):
    return sqrt(x)

def i(x):
    return -x

def j(x):
    return -x*x

def k(x):
    return -sqrt(x)

functions = [f, g, h, i, j, k]
```

And now I'm trying to plot these functions.

I tried

`plt.plot(f(x), g(x), h(x))`

but I get the following error:

> TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

I figure this is because I'm using the square root which has two solutions. But really, I'm trying to do something like:

`plt.plot(*functions)`

Any advice?

Comment: Please, provide a verifiable example even it's bugged : it shows what you tried so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`math.sqrt`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.sqrt) accepts only scalar values.
Use [`numpy.sqrt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.sqrt.html) to compute the square root of each value in a list or NumPy array:

```
In [5]: math.sqrt(np.array([0,1]))
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

In [6]: np.sqrt(np.array([0,1]))
Out[6]: array([ 0.,  1.])
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x):
    return x

def g(x):
    return x*x

def h(x):
    return np.sqrt(x)

def i(x):
    return -x

def j(x):
    return -x*x

def k(x):
    return -np.sqrt(x)

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
functions = [f, g, h, i, j, k]
for func in functions:
    plt.plot(func(x), label=func.__name__)
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

[image]